# Django install: 403 Forbidden

Tags: django, unix, centos6.5

I want to play around with Django, but I'm clueless on why I get a "Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /django_test/ on this server" message.

I'm working on a VPS with CentOS 6.5 installed, and I installed Python / Django and created a project in the folder:
/home/admin/domains/zwoop.be/public_html

I have a few other demo's and Wordpress sites running (like Laravel4) in this folder (linked to a subdomain, or just running there in a subfolder as test) and they run without any permission problem.

The things I've checked:

- Folder permissions (changed them with chmod -R 775);
- SELinux -> disabled;
- Owner: I tried to change from root to admin (also the owner for my other folders), which shouldn't be a problem. But without success.

I've searched a long time for this and I'm kinda desperate, because I want to get started with Django.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: At what point do you get this error message?

Comment: When I try to browse the path in the browser. I expected to see the Django welcome screen (without anything else).

Comment: Have you actually configured Django to work with a webserver?:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/

Comment: I have not yet done this. Strange, the tutorial didn't mention this at this point though, so I wonder if this will solve the problem regarding the permission.

Comment: Because the tutorial is for playing around with it on your own development machine, not for deploying it to a server. You really shouldn't be trying to deploy straight away.

Comment: Ok, I see. On the server everything seems to be working and running just fine. I'd still like to get it working though, just for the sake of getting rid of the uncertainty. I'm pretty new to this, so it's the first time I'm trying out Python / Django. I'll check it out, thanks!

Comment: @DanielRoseman is right. It's too hard to start learning Django from deployment on a production machine when all you need to run devserver on your development machine is just one command.

Comment: I understand, but I feel kinda uncertain starting a new technology when I don't even know technically how to deploy it (get it to work) on my server. I've read about 7 chapters straight about how Django works, and I find the workflow clear. But if I don't even know how to deploy a project to make it work, I guess it doesn't make a lot of sense getting started at all. I don't know if that makes any sense to you. I prefer not to let these worries / concerns linger.